# Is it any way to throw errors inside promises in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging

js Gurus,

I am writing a parser in nodejs (actually iojs) and I have a typical callback pyramid of doom handled with promises. The issue taking 70% of my time is finding errors inside promises.

```
    function parseHomeData(home, web) {
      var deferred = Q.defer();
      var homepage = web.url(home).then(function () {
// any error here dies silently
        parser.getHomeInfo(homepage).then(function (parsedHome) {
            console.log(parsedHome);
            deferred.resolve(parsedHome);

        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            throw new Error(err);
        });
    }, function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

If I uncomment "any errors here dies silently" it will do. The only way, is to wrap inside try/catch block but even there I can only console.log(error) throw new Error does not work. Is it any way to run iojs with automatic failure option? 
Thx

Comment: Thx, never heard about it before. Will take a look. Thx for the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promises catch exceptions and turn them into rejections.  So, if you are inside a `.then()` handler and you throw an exception, that will generate the same result as returning a rejected promise.  This is how promises work.

So, to make your code work, you just need to return the actual promise that `web.url()` is creating.  This will also get rid of some antipatterns you have where you are creating promises unnecessarily.

```
function parseHomeData(home, web) {
    return web.url(home).then(function () {
        // any exception error here becomes the rejected promise
        return parser.getHomeInfo(homepage).then(function (parsedHome) {
            console.log(parsedHome);
            return parsedHome;
        }, function (err) {
            // this handler is only needed if you need the console.log(err) here
            console.log(err);
            throw new Error(err);
        });
    }, function (err) {
        // this handler is only needed if you need the console.log(err) here
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    });
};
```

In fact, without the `console.log()` statements, the code could all just collapse to this:

```
function parseHomeData(home, web) {
    return web.url(home).then(parser.getHomeInfo.bind(parser));
}
```

This code block combines several things:

1. Returns the `web.url()` promise so if it is rejected for any reason (such as a throw in your `.then()` handler, that will be returned as a rejected promise from your `parseHomeData()` function.
2. No need to create your own Q promise when you already have one you can just return.
3. Once you implement items 1) and 2) above, then rather than `resolve()` and `reject()`, you can just return or throw from within the `.then()` handler.

You can read more about promise anti-patterns in these references:

[Promise Anti-patterns (Bluebird github)](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns)

[Promise Anti-patterns (Tao of Code)](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/)

[Promise Patterns & Anti-Patterns](http://www.datchley.name/promise-patterns-anti-patterns/)

Comment: Thank you so much. looking forward for a code but if you have time of course and if you can write a bit more about anipatterns - I like to code well :-)

Comment: Thank you, for your time, jfriend.

Comment: @Svitlana - several anti-pattern references added to my question.

Comment: @Svitlana - I added an even shorter version of the answer.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. You made a small error in the code, but I got:
[ReferenceError: homepage is not defined] 
:-)

Comment: Just want to thank you once more, jfriend, I finished my project - I follow your recommendations and everything works. The only issue I do not really understand why it works, but I will read more and thx for your help :-). Adious

Comment: @Svitlana - glad you got it to work.  The reference to `homepage` comes straight from your original code.  Was that supposed to be `home`?  Promises take a little while to fully understand.  You can start using simple `promise.then()` functionality pretty quickly, but returning promises from within `.then()` handlers takes a little while for the brain to fully understand.  But, it's definitely worth learning and using.  I learned it originally by reading a few articles on the web and by following all questions here marked "promise".

Comment: Well, I guess I messed it up, never mind, parsedHome is a promise, sorry for that. At least, I understand about promises "composability/chainability" and will avoid Bluebird Anti-pattern and will throw an Error instance and return value in success branch. Well, it's a great difference and it's hard to get it from reading about promises. SO thank you for open my mind and have a great day, jfriend!

Comment: Sorry, jfriend, for not leaving you in peace :-). But I have a small issue with my program and I wonder whether you can take a look. chicagobusinessintelligence1@gmail.com 
I will reimburse your time, send me your paypal email if you have 10 - 15 mins to review. Thx